# Hide status bar without automatically adjusting a navigation bar's frame

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

When hiding the status bar in a `UINavigationController`-based app by using:

`UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarHidden(true, withAnimation: .None)`

the `UINavigationBar`'s frame is adjusted. This is because the status bar is a `UIView` itself and the top of the navigation bar is constrained to the bottom of the status bar. So when the status bar is moved offscreen, the navigation bar moves up with it.

I've tried a number of ways to prevent this behavior. I've tried manually assigning a frame to the navigation bar to no avail. I've tried subclassing `UINavigationBar` and overriding `sizeThatFits()` while checking if the status bar is hidden or not and assigning a frame that way. Nothing. I've read other SO posts but no one seems to have a working solution. Help?

Comment: Related - has anyone been recently rejected for manually grabbing the status bar and adjusting its frame in a case like this?

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: @NitishMakhija it's been so long I honestly can't remember if I ever did. Sorry!